# Changing the JSON format for spring-data-rest

Tags: spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

Currently `spring-data-rest` is returning JSON in HAL format in a `spring-boot` project of mine.  I am using an ember.js frontend and want to use jsonapi (http://jsonapi.org/) specification.

How might I register a new JSON formatting strategy given I will need to write the formatter myself as one does not exists yet?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can customize the HATEOAS that Spring Data REST produces:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.customizing-json-output

If you need to completely replace the JSON representation with your own, then you can write and register your own `org.springframework.core.convert.converter`

Or you write your custom REST endpoints in a plain old @RepositoryRestController  and implement your own REST endpoints.  (<= I suggest try this)